# Calculating the center of mass of a solid

Tags: integration, centroid

Let T be the solid consisting of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$, $z=cos(x^2+y^2)$ and the surface $z=0$, and let $F(x,y,z)=(-xz-2y)i+(x^2-yz)j+(z^2+1)k$

A) What is the center of mass of T?

B) (Irrelevant but it exists). I assume the F(x,y,z) should be used here.

I know the answer is: $(0,0,\frac{\left(2+sin\left(2\right)\right)}{8\cdot sin\left(1\right)})$

Given by: $\frac{\int _0^{2\pi }\:\int _0^1\:\int _0^{cos\left(r^2\right)}\:z\:r\:dr\:d\theta }{M=\int _0^{2\pi }\:\int _0^1\:cos\left(r^2\right)\:r\:dr\:d\theta \:\:}$

I have been sitting for quite a while, trying to solve the problem not using the formula:
$z=\frac{\int _{\:}^{\:}\:\int _{\:}\:\int _S\:zf\left(x,y,z\right)dx\:dy\:dz}{\int _{\:}^{\:}\:\int _{\:}\:\int _S\:f\left(x,y,z\right)dx\:dy\:dz}$
because I was not given the $f(x,y,z)$ directly in the problem. I assumed it could be anything and that there must have been another way to solve the problem, including somehow using the vector field given.

Is there another way to solve the problem given the relevant information or should I always assume $f(x,y,z) $is 1 given such problems where $f(x,y,z)$ is not stated.

Comment: "$x^2+y^2=1, z=\cos(x^2+y^2)$" does not describe a cylinder, but just a circle hanging at an altitude of $\cos(1)$ above the $xy$-plane.

Comment: And what is the purpose of defining the function $F(x,y,z)$ which is never mentioned again afterwards?

Comment: @HenningMakholm F(x,y,z) is in the problem description, and I assume $F(x,y,z)$ is supposed to be used in part B) of the problem. I updated the original post with this information.  But in attempting problem A, I was also open to the idea of somehow using F(x,y,z) to calculate the center of mass. I am not sure if that is even possible.

Comment: If $f(x, y, z)$ denotes density of material, you're meant to take $f(x, y, z) = 1$ in part A (and the vector field $F$ is immaterial).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang How would I know that given the problem as stated? The f(x,y,z) is not given in the problem. I did solve the problem by doing that though. Like I said, not given $f(x,y,z)$ directly I assumed f(x,y,z) could be anything, any function, and there must have been another way to solve the problem and I spent a lot of time trying to find another way. In the end I just gave up and put 1 into formula, and out came the right answer. A very direct question is "is there another way to solve the problem?", or should I always use the formula and assume $f(x,y,z)=1$ when $f(x,y,z)$ is not giv.

Comment: It's technically imprecise of the book to omit $f$ (unless the book asked for the _centroid_, a geometric concept rather than a physical one), but generally if someone asks for a "center of mass" without specifying a density function, it's assumed the density is constant. Then one may as well take the density to be $1$, since constants factor out of integrals, and can be canceled.